# How to make WordPress thumbnails same size

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

After added Ads in my WordPress page the next thumbnail on mobile responsive goes oversize. I'm adding picture to better understand this. The first one is good, second goes Ad and the third one is oversized. When I turn on Ad blocker everything is okay. So probably the problem is Advanced Ads plugin.

[image: WordPress mobile rensponsive]

I tried add some CSS like border-box or etc. But It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should find the problem if you would use the developer tools of the broswer.

Comment: We can't debug an image. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It will be the width of those sections that need to be styled. But we can't help you with an image because it could be 1000 things. Open your browser page source on that page and copy/paste the HTML and CSS here so we can see what is happening.